# Create auto-complete TextField in Pythonista 3

Tags: python, pythonista

I want to create an auto-complete TextField.

I mean - when you type something in the field and see a prompt list below. The prompt list is an array with possible values. The best way to explain it show a similar picture.

[image: Auto-complete example]

I already have some experience in Pythonista 3 but it was not UI programming experience.

I understand this is complex and that maybe I should use an additional View and Delegate mechanism but I don't have any idea how to start. I have already spent several days in Google looking for a solution, but I can't, in the context of Pythonista.

Has anybody done this? Or could someone provide useful links for reading?

Comment: @Jerry Stratton thank you for improved grammar, spelling!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A drop-down list can be created in Pythonista using a TableView. TableViews are really just single-column lists, they’re not just for tables.

So the steps would be:

1. Create a tableview.
2. Align it with your text field.
3. Hide the tableview until typing starts.
4. Update the tableview’s item list with the auto-completion options whenever the typing changes.
5. Potentially hide the tableview again when typing ends.

You can hide any view by setting its `.hidden` property to `True`.

You can do things when typing starts in a TextField by creating a delegate object that implements `textfield_did_change`.

You set a TableView to have a list of items by giving the TableView a `data_source`, probably an implementation of `ui.ListDataSource`. Whenever the `items` property on the data source changes, the list of options will also automatically change.

You can react to the user choosing an option from the TableView by setting an `action` on the TableView’s `delegate`.

The documentation for TableView, TextField, ListDataSource, delegates, and actions, can be found at Pythonista’s [Native GUI for iOS](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/ui.html) documentation.

Here is a basic example:

```
# documentation at http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/ui.html
import ui

# the phoneField delegate will respond whenever there is typing
# the delegate object will combine phoneField delegate, tableview delegate, and data source, so that it can share data
class AutoCompleter(ui.ListDataSource):
    def textfield_did_change(self, textfield):
        dropDown.hidden = False
        # an arbitrary list of autocomplete options
        # you will have a function that creates this list
        options = [textfield.text + x for x in textfield.text]

        # setting the items property automatically updates the list
        self.items = options
        # size the dropdown for up to five options
        dropDown.height = min(dropDown.row_height * len(options), 5*dropDown.row_height)

    def textfield_did_end_editing(self, textfield):
        #done editing, so hide and clear the dropdown
        dropDown.hidden = True
        self.items = []

        # this is also where you might act on the entered data
        pass

    def optionWasSelected(self, sender):
        phoneField.text = self.items[self.selected_row]
        phoneField.end_editing()

autocompleter = AutoCompleter(items=[])
autocompleter.action = autocompleter.optionWasSelected

# a TextField for phone number input
phoneField = ui.TextField()
phoneField.delegate = autocompleter
phoneField.keyboard_type = ui.KEYBOARD_PHONE_PAD
phoneField.clear_button_mode = 'while_editing'

# the drop-down menu is basically a list of items, which in Pythonista is a TableView
dropDown = ui.TableView()
dropDown.delegate = autocompleter
dropDown.data_source = autocompleter
# hide the dropdown until typing starts
dropDown.hidden = True

# create interface
mainView = ui.View()
mainView.add_subview(phoneField)
mainView.add_subview(dropDown)

# present the interface before aligning fields, so as to have the window size available
mainView.present()

# center text field
phoneField.width = mainView.width*.67
phoneField.height = 40

phoneField.x = mainView.width/2 - phoneField.width/2
phoneField.y = mainView.height/3 - phoneField.height/2

# align the dropdown with the phoneField
dropDown.x = phoneField.x
dropDown.y = phoneField.y + phoneField.height
dropDown.width = phoneField.width
dropDown.row_height = phoneField.height
```

On my iPhone, this code creates an interface that looks like this:

[image: Sample code output on iPhone 8]

Comment: Wow!
Thank you a lot for this clear explanation!
I'm new in UI programming so your answer is really very helpful for me.